# Show that $(α^{1/u_{n+1}}-1)^{1/(n+1)}<(α^{1/u_{n}}-1)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $α>2$ be a real number. Let $(u_{n})_{n}$ be an increasing sequence.

Then my **question** is: Show that

$$(α^{1/u_{n+1}}-1)^{1/(n+1)}<(α^{1/u_{n}}-1)^{1/n}$$

**Add.**

We have:

$$(α^{1/u_{n}}-1)^{1/n}>(α^{1/u_{n+1}}-1)^{1/n}>(α^{1/u_{n+1}}-1)^{1/(n+1)}$$ since $$1/u_{n}>1/u_{n+1}$$ and $$(1/n)>1/(n+1)$$

Comment: But, the inequality need not hold. Take $u_1$ really large, and $u_2 = u_1 + 1$.

Comment: @DanielFischer: This is an exercice.

Comment: Well, people make mistakes. Also when giving exercises. If you haven't missed some further constraint, the inequality need not hold in all cases.

Comment: Are the $u_n$ real numbers also or must they be integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality

$$x^{1/n} > x^{1/(n+1)}$$

only holds for $x > 1$. For $0 < x < 1$, the reverse inequality holds.

Choosing $\alpha = e$ (other choices of $\alpha$ correspond to a scaling of $(u_n)$ by a factor of $\log \alpha$), we have

$$e^{1/u_n} - 1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k!}\cdot \frac{1}{u_n^k} = \frac{1}{u_n} + \frac{1}{2u_n^2} + \dotsc = \frac{1}{u_n}\left(1 + O(u_n^{-1})\right),$$

and thus

$$(e^{1/u_n}-1)^{1/n} = u_n^{-1/n}\left(1 + O(n^{-1}u_n^{-1})\right).$$

For large $n$, the second factor is very close to $1$, and whether

$$(e^{1/u_n}-1)^{1/n} > (e^{1/u_{n+1}}-1)^{1/(n+1)}$$

holds or the inequality in the other direction holds depends primarily on whether

$$u_n^{1/n} < u_{n+1}^{1/(n+1)}$$

or the reverse. Both can happen.

We can also have $(e^{1/u_{n+1}}-1)^{1/(n+1)} > (e^{1/u_n}-1)^{1/n}$ for small $n$, consider e.g. $u_1 = 4,\, u_2 = 5$. Then

$$(e^{1/u_1}-1)^{1/1} = e^{1/4}-1 < \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{4^k} = \frac{1}{3}$$

and

$$(e^{1/u_2}-1)^{1/2} = \sqrt{e^{1/5}-1} > \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{5}} > \frac{1}{3}.$$